# Perl syntax errors on hash generating script

Tags: perl, encryption, syntax-error

I am getting the following errors when running the code:

```
syntax error line 5, near "use Digest::MD5

sub makeKey 
"
syntax error at line 8, near "}"
syntax error at line 15, near ")
}"
Execution aborted due to compilation errors.
```

My script:

```
use lib '/home/me/Desktop/pm/MD5.pm';
use Digest::MD5

sub makeKey 
{
    my ($strPassword, $strRndk);
    $strKey = uc(md5Hash($strPassword)) + $strRndk + "Y(02.>'H}t\":E1" + md5Hash($strKey);
    return $strKey;
}

sub md5Hash 
{
    my ($strPassword);
    $strMd5 = md5_hex($strPassword);
    return substr($strMd5, 16, 16) + substr($strMd5, 0, 16);
}

makeKey('test', '1A2B3C');
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Digest::MDd5 needs to end with a semicolon.

Comment: I did that, but now I get "Parameter to use lib must be directory, not file on line 1", so I did that, and now I get
"Undefined subroutine &main::md5_hex called on line 14".

Answer (score 4):

Concerning your third (and final?) problem:

> "Undefined subroutine &main::md5_hex called on line 14"

[`Digest::MD5`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Digest%3a%3aMD5) doesn't export `md5_hex` (or anything else) by default, you have to explicitly tell it that it should export `md5_hex`:

```
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
```

or use the full `Digest::MD5::md5_hex` name.